# Where can I find a clean copy of Hyper-V 2012 InitialStore.xml?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

After much searching, I have been unable to find a clean copy of initialstore.xml, but my original copy was corrupted.  Most of the guides (e.g., http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2virtualization/thread/0531efcc-307d-4594-96af-df593ae7d2fa/ )I have encountered tend to have instructions like, "Step 1: Have a second, working copy of Hyper-V", but I don't currently have anywhere to put it.  Sadly using Hyper-V 2008's initialstore.xml only partially works; they aren't completely the same.

Can anyone suggest where I can pull a copy of this file without reinstalling hyper-v?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mount the WIM file from your Windows CD. The .xml file should be in there somewhere.